# Difference between array.length != 0 and array != [] to reference a non-empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I use `array.length != 0` to reference the condition of a non-empty array for a while loop, the rest of the code works fine. However, if I use `array != []` to reference while an array is not empty, the same code gets TypeError (Cannot read properties of undefined) for the while loop.

I'm new to JavaScript. I thought either could mean the array is not empty, but apparently not. Can someone help explain the difference between `array.length != 0` and `array != []`? Thank you!!

Comment: Visit http://www.jsfuck.com/ and take a look at the `Basics`

Comment: JavaScript gives *references* to arrays. `[]` is a new array that has its own reference. These references are not equal. Not so with primitives, like numbers, where the comparison works as you intended.

Comment: @trincot Thanks so much for your quick and helpful response! I understand better now!